# Can't Access Go API on Windows Server from other device

Tags: http, go, server, port, rdp

I can't connect to my Go API on windows server, port allowed but still it didn't let me connect to the API from different devices, but my Go API work on localhost using postman

Changing port, change the e-channel.ini file but still can't connect

this is my code

```
package main

import (
    "flag"

    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "./config_db"
    "./controller"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    fileConfig := flag.String("f", "e_channel.ini", "config file")
    flag.Parse()
    config, err := config_db.LoadConfig(*fileConfig)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())

    }
    db := config_db.Connectdb()
    inDB := &controller.DB{DBE: db}
    r := gin.Default()

    fmt.Println("Listening at Port " + config.ListeningPort)
    r.Run(":" + config.ListeningPort)

}

func root(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "message": "welcome my api",
    })
}
```

and this is my e-channel.ini

```
{
    "app_name"       : "HELLOWORLD_API",
    "listening_port" : "1195",
    "host"           : "0.0.0.0",
    "port"           : "3306",
    "user"           : "root",
    "passwd"         : "",
    "dbname"        : "kube71"
}
```

i hope the API can be accessed by another devices.

Comment: The `Run()` method is returning an error. You just ignore the error at this point. If the port for example is already in use you won't know. So first thing refactor and check if there is an error, when you run the server.

Comment: so i need to make log first about everything happen ?

Comment: i don't understand what error, since it run perfect i think, any suggestion?

Comment: I guess @apxp is talking about the error returned by `Run` in case of error (https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Engine.Run). What your problem looks like is that TCP connections to the used port (1195) are not allowed. Have you opened it in the firewall?

Comment: Inbound and outbound rules been setted up for 1195, still its not allowed